# Editor submitting multiple time-wasting minor edits on old posts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Tonight the edit queue is full of proposed edits from one or more users who have excavated answers a year or more old and propose deletion of the answerers "Please google before asking" comment. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4938528).

I am rejecting these edits; most of the answers should be deleted as link only anyway. How can I tell this editor to stop wasting our time?

Comment: Custom reasons and comments on the user's answers come to mind. If their edit has been approved, you can also ping them using a comment on the edited post. If they persistently continue, you could probably flag for mod attention.

Comment: snide comments like "google before asking" don't belong in answers(they belong in the comments), and the suggested edit queue is never that big.  Yes, this user is grinding for reputation, but it's mostly benign.

Comment: The user is also making some pretty nice improvements to some link-only-answers. I'd reject edits that aren't substantial, but stay objective and make sure you don't just see the person's name and think, "oh no, not again."  For instance:  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12610854/revisions

Comment: @SamIam I agree and I started to leave a comment along these lines for the original answerer, until I realized the post was from Dec 21 '11.

Comment: @jmort253 I approved that one. Maybe it's time to just watch TV for a while.

Comment: @user3114046 - Lol, yeh. Sometimes it's good to take a break.  Your eyes can definitely glaze over after reviewing one too many posts.

Comment: For the sake of it, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2919723/revisions <- thats just trolling right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also would have rejected the edit you've used as an example.

But the reviewer is correct with their suggestion, so why reject it?

`Google is your friend` is indeed unnecessary. But that example is a bad answer - just a line of code and no explanation. Any edit suggestions on that answer should be *adding* content rather than removing it. If no content is being added then it needs to be down voted - it's an answer and it may even be correct, but it's not a good quality one. Fundamentally the edit suggestion doesn't improve the answer at all, not in the way that it needs improving.

If enough of the reviewer's suggestions are rejected then they will be automatically edit banned for a while.

Comment: I agree that the problem with these edits is not the proposal, but the low quality of the answers (which would go into the low quality queue if posted today) and that most of them are a year or more old.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with edit suggestions on older posts, the rep point incentive is there for a reason and some of the older posts need it. I just checked that user's last 10 suggestions, overall he's doing okay. The occasional rejection because the answer was crap might make him pay more attention.